# MongoDB query distinct in subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm using Mongoose with NodeJS (typescript). 
I'm trying to sum the count per location. Example output :

```
[ 
 { name : "Bronx", count : 6 }, 
 { name : "Brooklyn", count : 6 }, 
 { name : "Manhattan", count : 6 }, 
 { name : "Queens", count : 6 } 
]
```

> Current data model:

```
data:
[
    {
        "news": {
            "_id": "5c7615a4ef5238a6c47cbcb9",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "_id": "5c7615a4ef5238a6c47cbcc6",
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "Manhattan",                        
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7615a4ef5238a6c47cbcc8",
                            "count": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7615a4ef5238a6c47cbcc7",
                            "count": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    { 
     .... 
    }

]
```

The last query that I build was :

```
DataModel.aggregate([
{ "$unwind": "$data.news.locations" },
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$data.news.locations",
        "count": { "$sum": "$$data.news.locations.zipcodes.count" }
    }
}]).exec(function(err, results){
    if (err) throw err;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));

     });
```

But I'm new handle queries in MongoDB with Mongoose, so any help I really appreciate. thanks.

Comment: What have you tried and what part of the problem do you not understand? You are expected to have made some attempt rather than just expecting someone to write all the code for you. Show your attempt please, and then someone can help with the parts that are wrong.

Comment: @NeilLunn You're right, I just edited the question with my last attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were kind of close, just a few changes:

```
DataModel.aggregate([
  // Each array needs $unwind separately
  { "$unwind": "$data" },

  // And then down to the next one
  { "$unwind": "$data.news.locations" },

  // Group on the grouping key
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$data.news.locations.name",
    "count": { "$sum": { "$sum": "$data.news.locations.children.count" } }
  }}
],(err,results) => {
   // remaining handling
})
```

So since you have arrays inside an array and you want to get down to the `"name"` property inside the `"locations"` you need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to that point. You must [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) each array level separately.

Technically there is still the `children` array as well, but [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) can be used to [*"sum an array of values"*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#use-in-project-stage) as well as *"accumulate for a grouping key"*. Hence the `$sum: { $sum` statement within the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

Returns:

```
{ "_id" : "Manhattan", "count" : 5 }
```

From the detail supplied in the question.